# Impala SQL - Multiple Conditions in Select Criteria

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with below columns and data.There are set of rules that i need to apply on this table and get the records in the output.

```
src_sys_nm  last_tmstp                 src_sys_id
CIT         2016-08-31 12:30:43.720     291289
CIT         2016-08-31 16:44:19.930     291289
UFE         2017-11-15 09:05:37.487     291289
UFE         2017-12-12 15:10:35.707     291289
CIT         2017-12-13 15:11:22:540     291289
EPRO        2018-06-19 12:25:23.053     259858
EPRO        2018-06-22 15:28:35.433     259858
UFE         2017-12-12 16:37:10.130     259858
EPRO        2017-12-13 15:11:22:540     259858
UFE         2017-11-15 09:05:37.487     359423111
UFE         2017-12-12 15:10:35.707     359423111
UFE         2017-12-12 16:37:10.130     359423111
CIT         2016-08-31 12:30:43.720     291287
CIT         2016-08-31 16:44:19.930     291287
EPRO        2018-06-19 12:25:23.053     391289
EPRO        2018-06-22 15:28:35.433     391289
```

Rule 1: The records on the report should be unique on src_sys_id.

Rule 2: If there are records with same src_sys_id under the src_sys_nm - UFE, then the UFE record with latest time stamp need to be selected.

Rule 3: If there are records with same src_sys_id under the src_sys_nm - UFE and CIT, then the UFE record with latest time stamp need to be selected.

Rule 4: If there are records with same src_sys_id under the src_sys_nm - UFE and EPRO, then the UFE record with latest time stamp need to be selected.

Rule 5: If there are records with same src_sys_id under the src_sys_nm - CIT or EPRO, then the record with latest time stamp need to be selected for
CIT and EPRO.

The expected output based on these rules

```
src_sys_nm  last_tmstp                 src_sys_id
UFE         2017-12-12 15:10:35.707     291289
UFE         2017-12-12 16:37:10.130     259858
UFE         2017-12-12 16:37:10.130     359423111
CIT         2016-08-31 16:44:19.930     291287
EPRO        2018-06-22 15:28:35.433     391289
```

Any help is appreciated. I need the query in Impala SQL.

Comment: Format the code or table well

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to perform your logic in two different parts grouping by src_sys_id. When we have UFE in the group and when we don't

```
-- when we do have UFE in the group we order order by src_sys_nm letting UFE first and timestamp
select src_sys_nm, last_tmstp, src_sys_id from (
select 
*,
MAX(case when 'UFE' = src_sys_nm then 1 else 0 end) over (PARTITION BY src_sys_id) as ufe_in_group,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY src_sys_id order by (case when 'UFE' = src_sys_nm then 1 else 0 end) desc,  last_tmstp desc) as position
from t30
) t  where ufe_in_group = 1 and position = 1
union all
-- when we do not have UFE en group we simply group by src_sys_id and src_sys_nm and order by timestamp
select src_sys_nm, last_tmstp, src_sys_id from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY src_sys_id, src_sys_nm order by last_tmstp desc) as position
 from (
select 
*,
MAX(case when 'UFE' = src_sys_nm then 1 else 0 end) over (PARTITION BY src_sys_id) as ufe_in_group
from t30
) t  where ufe_in_group = 0 
) t2 where position = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch hlagos. i tried it and it works..i am trying to understand the logic.